# Object is disappearing when moved on viewport shading

Tags: 3d-view

When using viewport shading, in object mode, whenever I move, rotate or scale an object, only the outliner of the object moves. The object remains in its original place.
To fix this problem, I have to switch to edit mode and go back to object mode, only then the object is positioned where it should be every time.

[image]version 2.83 with my key configure imported only. (I had the same problem before in v2.82)

Do you have any ideas for solving this? or you think what im doing wrong?   Thanks

Edit : still same problem continiues

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Comment: Hello, most likely you should update your graphic card's drivers

Comment: I have updated the driver but still problem continiues :(